# sf::String member of class reverts to blank

Tags: c++, string, sfml

These lines of code are run:

```
Enemy* enemy = new Enemy(m_pSceneManager,"enemy"+ss.str());
std::cout << "Enemy name = " << std::string(enemy->name) << std::endl;
Add(enemy->name,enemy);
```

in EnemyManager.cpp. EnemyManager inherits from GameObjectManager:

```
void GameObjectManager::Add(sf::String name,VisibleGameObject* obj){
    std::cout << "GameObjectManager obj name = " << std::string(obj->name) << std::endl;
    gameObjects.insert(std::pair<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>(name,obj));
}
```

Enemy inherits from VisibleGameObject, which both have a public sf::String 'name' variable but only Enemy initializes it at any point (in its constructor). The output in the console window is this:

```
Enemy name = enemy0
GameObjectManager obj name =
```

Why does the `name` revert to nothing? I'm assuming it's something to do with the fact that the argument is a VisibleGameObject* and not an Enemy* - if it is, how can I work around this? If I've made a mistake somewhere else, please tell me if there are any details I am missing that are required.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, as you say *both have a public sf::String 'name' variable but only Enemy initializes it at any point (in its constructor).* , there are two `name` subojects: one is a member of `Enemy` and another is a subobject of `VisibleGameObject`. Inside function `Add` you explicitly refer to the latter one, so that is what you get, and it is not initialised.

You probably want to make `name` a virtual function returning string; this will make function `Add` to employ runtime polymorphism and call `name()` from derived class, i.e. from `Enemy`.

Simpler (but not necessarily better) design would be to make `name` protected or public member of `VisibleGameObject` and let `Enemy` set it; that also means you will most likely want to remove `name` from `Enemy`, otherwise `name` inherited from `VisibleGameObject` will be hidden.

Comment: thanks, I was under the impression that making something with the same name would overwrite it (I tried 'virtual name' before).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your description correctly, your code looks like this:

```
struct VisibleGameObject {
    sf::String name;
};

struct Enemy : VisibleGameObject {
    Enemy(SceneManager*, sf::String newName) : VisibleGameObject(), name(newName)
    sf::String name;
};

struct GameObjectManager {
    void GameObjectManager::Add(sf::String name,VisibleGameObject* obj){
        std::cout << "GameObjectManager obj name = " << std::string(obj->name) << std::endl;
        gameObjects.insert(std::pair<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>(name,obj));
    }
private:
    std::map<sf::String, VisibleGameObject*> gameObjects;
};

struct EnemyManager : GameObjectManager {
    void foo() {
        //This code probably leads to a memory leak, but you might have solved it in some
        //way that you are not showing.
        Enemy* enemy = new Enemy(m_pSceneManager,"enemy"+ss.str());
        std::cout << "Enemy name = " << std::string(enemy->name) << std::endl;
        Add(enemy->name,enemy);
    }
};
```

What this means is - when the `Enemy` object is constructed, the `Enemy::name` variable is initialised to hold `"enemy"+ss.str()`. However, the `VisibleGameObject::name` variable (which is in the VisibleGameObject part of the `Enemy`) is initialised to hold its default value (in which it holds no text).

In `EnemyManager::foo`, the name variable that is referenced is the one in `Enemy`. In `GameObjectManager::Add`, the `name` variable that is referenced is the one in the `VisibleGameObject` base member of `Enemy`.  `VisibleGameObject::name` still has its default value, and so nothing gets printed.